# || operators must be convertible to logical scalar values in case of an empty matrix

Tags: matlab, operators

Consider the following code

```
t = ones(3,5)
Ind2save = find(t(1,:) == 0,1,'first')
```

So for example I am trying to find if even the first zero of the first row, so if the first element is a non zero then

```
if(Ind2save ~= 1 )
    disp('no')
end
```

now for the above condition it doesn't display 'no' because the condition is not fulfilled but because all the rows are filled and `Ind2save` is an empty matrix so we another condition to check if it is fully filled then

```
if(Ind2save > 1 || isempty(Ind2save))
    disp('no')
end
```

I get the following error

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

I searched for the reasons due to which this error is caused and in majority of the cases people were comparing two vectors so a better idea was to replace `||` with `|` but in my case the conditions are never vectors but `Ind2save > 1` returns an empty matrix , does anyone know why is the reason for that? How can I accommodate both the conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because in your case `Ind2save` is empty (`[]`) therefore the first part of your condition can't be used with `||` since `[] > 1` doesn't yield a logical scalar (it results in `[]`).

In order to fix this, you can to flip the order of your conditions such that you check if the array is empty *first*.

```
if isempty(Ind2save) || Ind2save > 1
```

The reason that this works is that if `Ind2Save` is empty, then the first condition evaluates to `true` therefore short-circuiting the rest of the checks.

You may have other issues if for some reason `Ind2save` is a vector. In that case you could need to so something to convert it to a logical scalar:

```
if isempty(Ind2save) || ismember(1, Ind2save)
```